# Is the modeling strategy of GAM in MGCV equivalent to ridge regression when there are no smoothing terms?

Tags: r, ridge-regression, smoothing, mgcv

According to GAM, it utilizes a penalized likelihood, which is maximized by penalized iteratively re-weighted least squares (P-IRLS), to obtain parameter estimations. The likelihood is defined as:

[image]

The structure is quite close to ridge regression with L2 penalty with an extra S matrix in the penalty term, but from the book, I learned that the S matrix is 0 when we have non-smoothing terms. That is to say, if I specify a model without any smoothing terms, the likelihood will not have any penalization. However, I did some comparative experiment and found out that the GAM results are quite close to ridge regression results, but not completely equivalent.

Did I miss any details in the GAM algorithm that there exists some penalization for non-smoothing terms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no penalization applied by default to the parametric terms of a GAM fitted by {mgcv}. If you tried to fit:

```r
gam(y ~ x + z)
```

you would get back the equivalent (up to details of the actual algorithm and implementation of course) of

```r
glm(y ~ x + z)
```

because these terms are *not* subject to any penalization.

However, what you say is correct; that *is* a ridge penalty on the coefficients $\boldsymbol{\beta}$, it's just that it doesn't apply to the non smooth terms in the model (by default). Hence

```r
gam(y ~ s(x) + z)
```

would see a ridge-like penalty controlling the wiggliness (smoothness) of the `s(x)` term, while the `z` term would not be subject to any penalty.

You *can* get ridge penalties on the parametric terms in the model (the `z` term above) using the `paraPen` mechanism and argument to `gam()` and there the penalty is a ridge penalty, where $\mathbf{S}$ has the form of an identity matrix.

Comment: I haven't been able to find practical examples of how to implement an L2-like penalization for the parametric terms with `gam`, e.g., how to specify a `paraPen` list that would be similar to a lambda coefficient in `glmnet`. If I understand, to penalize the parametric terms we pass an identity matrix to `paraPen` like you mentioned (with nrow and ncol the length of the coefficient vector?), but how would the equivalent of lambda be specified with `paraPen`? Or is that learned during fitting along with the penalty for the smooth terms?

Comment: It's learned alongside the other model coefficients and smoothing parameters. I recently posted an answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/593177/1390) that uses `paraPen`.