# How to perform ridge penalisation on an interaction between discrete and continuous variables in `mgcv`?

Tags: regularization, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

Using the `paraPen` term and `gamma` to control how much penalisation, what is the correct structure of penalty matrix input for `paraPen` for an interaction to be penalised?

In the case of a numeric variable we would use:

`paraPen = list("numeric_variable" = list(rank = 1, diag(1)))`

In the case of a factor/character variable we would use:

```
paraPen = list("categorical_variable" = list(list(rank = length(unique(.data$categorical_variable)) - 1,
                                diag(length(unique(.data$categorical_variable)) - 1))
```

However, how would the list be structured to penalise the terms in an interaction of `numeric_variable:categorical_variable`?

Would it be the unique combination of factor levels and the numeric variable name, without the reference level, or is there a better way of specifying linear predictor interaction terms?

The numeric and categorical examples have been found from:

- [fitting a gam with constraints on parameters to deal with separation in parametric terms](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/593177/fitting-a-gam-with-constraints-on-parameters-to-deal-with-separation-in-parametr)
- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/gam.models.html

Thank you for any help.